# Foundation Cannot read property 'bg_class' of undefined

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I am experimenting with javascript Modules. I can manage to retrieve modal content and display this in a reveal modal but when I want to close the modal I get a javascript error message and the modal does not close.

Here is the javascript code:

```
  var Order = (function (window, document, $){

    var Order = function(_id){
        this.id = _id;
    };

    Order.prototype = {
        id:null,
        constructor: Order, 
        test: function(){
            alert(this.id);
        }, 
        displayOrder: function(){   
            $.get("/orders/dialog_vieworder/"+this.id, function(data){
                var modal = $("#content").append('<div data-reveal />').attr('class', 'reveal-modal').html(data);               
                modal.foundation('reveal', 'open'); 
            });
        }
    };

    return Order;
})(window, document, jQuery);

$(function(){
    o1 = new Order(60000);  
    o1.displayOrder();
});
```

Here is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bg_class' of undefined
```

Help is very much appreciated

Comment: Have you [initialized your application](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either upgrade your foundation version, or change this...

If you have foundation.reveal.js
find this line

```
var settings = $('[data-reveal].open').data('reveal-init'),
bg_clicked = $(e.target)[0] === $('.' + settings.bg_class)[0];
```

and change the second line to this

```
bg_clicked = $(e.target)[0] === $('.' + ( settings ? settings.bg_class : null))[0];
```

If you have a minified version then do a search for bg_class
There should only be two. Find the line that will somewhat resemble this

```
i=e(t.target)[0]===e("." + r.bg_class)[0];
```

Then change it to this

```
i=e(t.target)[0]===e("." + (r?r.bg_class:null))[0];
```

You should be good to go.

Here is the issue on github

[Foundation Github bug](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3766)